# How to link GLAD using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, lnk2001, glad

I'm trying to setup GLAD in my project. But I keep getting multiple linking error like this one:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glad_glClear
```

here are the part of the CMake file that are related to GLAD:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(AR)

...

# Set Glad library
set(GLAD_DIR C:/tools/CPP/glad)

...

add_library(glad ${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c)

target_include_directories(glad PUBLIC ${GLAD_DIR}/include)

...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I tried moving the `glad.c` in multiple folder, but it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: ***I tried moving the glad.c in multiple folder,*** That should have nothing to do with  a linker problem as once you compile the `c` file it's not involved in the linking.

Comment: ***What am I doing wrong ?*** My guess is you have some problem in the part where you link  to glad but you did not show that.

Comment: Looks like this bug report could be the answer: [https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/issues/113](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/issues/113)

Comment: you are missing a `target_link_libraries` somewhere

Comment: @AhmedAEK But the GLAD library does not have .lib files, it just contains a .c and a .h

Comment: add_library() attempts to create a library from whatever source files you give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point `include_directories()` at the GLAD headers and toss `glad.c` into the `add_executable()` source file list.  `target_link_libraries()`'s library list doesn't need to change.

All together:

```
...
include_directories( SYSTEM "external/glad/include" )

add_executable( app-name "src/main.cpp" "external/glad/src/glad.c" )

target_link_libraries( app-name )
...
```